# Making decorators produce pickle-serializable functions

Tags: python, pickle

Why is it that this works:

```
import pickle
from functools import wraps

def wrapper(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _func(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _func


def foo(a: int):
    return a + 1

foo = wrapper(foo)

pickle.dumps(foo)  # okay!
```

But this does not:

```
def foo(a: int):
    return a + 1


_foo = wrapper(foo)

pickle.dumps(_foo)  # not okay!
```

The latter gives me the error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function foo at 0x12e116b00>: it's not the same object as __main__.foo
```

If I do a

```
_foo.__qualname__ = '_foo'
```

it'll make `_foo` pickle-able though.

But I'd like my `wrapper` function to take care of that so I'll be able to use it to decorate functions without losing their serializability or having to add the `__qualname__` thing "manually".

Comment: That requires `wrapper` to know what identifier its return value is being assigned to, so it can set the matching `__qualname__` on `_func` before returning it, which I suspect you'd have to do via [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).